# OrderItem matching query does not exist, while trying to add a product to cart

Tags: python, django

I am trying to add to cart a single product, but I have been encountering a problem and now I am stuck, I have tried different ways, but none of them worked. Please help as I am trying to learn django.

I have attached the `add_to_cart` function, urls.py and traceback of the error. Between function I have added a print function, it outputs

```
Internal Server Error (maybe)
```

Views:

```
@login_required
def add_to_cart(request, slug):
    item = AffProduct.objects.get(slug=slug)
    order_item = OrderItem.objects.get(
        item=item,
        user=request.user,
        ordered=False
    )
    for i in order_item:
        print(i)
    else:
        print("No orders in here")
    order_qs = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user, ordered=False)
    if order_qs.exists():
        order = order_qs[0]
        # check if the order item is in the order
        if order.items.filter(item__slug=item.slug).exists():
            order_item.quantity += 1
            order_item.save()
            messages.info(request, "This item quantity was updated.")
            return redirect("detailview")
        else:
            order.items.add(order_item)
            messages.info(request, "This item was added to your cart.")
            return redirect("detailview")
    else:
        ordered_date = timezone.now()
        order = Order.objects.create(
            user=request.user, ordered_date=ordered_date)
        order.items.add(order_item)
        messages.info(request, "This item was added to your cart.")
        return redirect("detailview")
```

Here is urls.py:

```
path('cart/', views.cart, name='cart'),
path('add-to-cart/<str:slug>/', add_to_cart, name='add-to-cart'),
```

This is my cart.html:

```
{% block content %}
  <main>
    <div class="container">

    <div class="table-responsive text-nowrap">
    <h2>Order Summary</h2>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Item title</th>
            <th scope="col">Price</th>
            <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
            <th scope="col">Total Item Price</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for order_item in object.items.all %}
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">{{ forloop.counter }}</th>
            <td>{{ order_item.item.product_title }}</td>
            <td>{{ order_item.item.sale_price }}</td>
            <td>
                <a href=""><i class="fas fa-minus mr-2"></i></a>
                {{ order_item.quantity }}
                <a href="{% url 'core:add-to-cart' order_item.item.slug %}"><i class="fas fa-plus ml-2"></i></a>
            </td>
            <td>
            {% if order_item.item.discount %}
                ${{ order_item.get_total_discount_item_price }}
                <span class="badge badge-primary">Saving ${{ order_item.get_amount_saved }}</span>
            {% else %}
                ${{ order_item.get_total_item_price }}
            {% endif %}
            <a style='color: red;' href="{% url 'core:remove-from-cart' order_item.item.slug %}">
                <i class="fas fa-trash float-right"></i>
            </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% empty %}
        <tr>
            <td colspan='5'>Your cart is empty</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
            <a class='btn btn-primary float-right' href='/'>Continue shopping</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        <!--{% if object.coupon %}
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4"><b>Coupon</b></td>
            <td><b>-${{ object.coupon.amount }}</b></td>
        </tr>
        {% endif %}-->
        {% if object.get_total %}
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4"><b>Order Total</b></td>
            <td><b>${{ object.get_total }}</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
            <a class='btn btn-warning float-right ml-2' href=''>Proceed to checkout</a>
            <a class='btn btn-primary float-right' href='/'>Continue shopping</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endif %}
        </tbody>
    </table>

    </div>

    </div>
  </main>

{% endblock content %}
```

Traceback is as below:

```
Internal Server Error: /onlineshopping/add-to-cart/hp-14-202/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\blink\myblink\onlineshopping\views.py", line 127, in add_to_cart
    order_item = OrderItem.objects.get(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 435, in get
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
onlineshopping.models.OrderItem.DoesNotExist: OrderItem matching query does not exist.
[10/Aug/2021 16:27:25] "GET /onlineshopping/add-to-cart/hp-14-202/ HTTP/1.1" 500 78902
```

Comment: And if i use :
`order_item = OrderItem.objects.filter(
        item=item,
        user=request.user,
        ordered=False
    )`
I encounter this error - 
`Field 'id' expected a number but got <QuerySet []>.`
And print function prints the value - `No orders in here`, which is in the else block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is throwing an error here so probably your database does not have order items whichever you want to fetch.

solution 1: handle get a query with try and catch.

```
try:
    order_item = OrderItem.objects.get(
        item=item,
        user=request.user,
        ordered=False
     )
except:
    order_item = None
```

solution 2:

fire filter query rather than get bcoz if get not found any item match with the condition it will throw an error but filter return none if there is not matching data found

Comment: Currently my table is empty. I am fetching the products from different model to display in a template so there is nothing in the OrderItem.

With Soln 1: I am facing this error:
`null value in column "orderitem_id" of relation "onlineshopping_order_items" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, 1, null).`

Comment: with filter query, Its says type error:`Field 'id' expected a number but got <QuerySet []>.`

Comment: use first()

model.objects.filter().first()

Comment: Same `Failing Row contains (2, 1, null) IntegrityError